# How to read a String from user in java (Socket Programming)

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a Client/Server program. When I tried to read String from client using **scanner.nextLine()** it does not wait for to write the text on console and process the next statement. I am writing program in BInary I/O because it is more efficient then text I/O.

```
    DataInputStream fromServer = null;
    DataOutputStream toServer = null;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{
         socket = new Socket("localhost",8000);
         toServer = new DataOutputStream
                            (socket.getOutputStream());
         fromServer = new DataInputStream
                            ( socket.getInputStream());


     }
    catch(IOException e){
             System.out.println(" Error in connection: " + e);
             e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connection is successfully Established...");

    try{
       //This does not processing
       setText = scanner.nextLine();

        toServer.writeUTF(setText);
        toServer.flush();

      // Get area from the server
    double area = fromServer.readDouble();

    // Display to the text area
    System.out.println("Text from Client " + setText + "\n");
    System.out.println("Response from server " + area + '\n');                  

    }
    catch(IOException e){
             System.out.println(" Error in connection: " + e);
             e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is:

```
    Text from Client

    Response from server 45.22
```

As you can see the program does not take input from the console

If I used next() instead of nextLine() then it runs fine, but I want to read the line of text up to enter key.

Comment: Is the server sending the delim new line character so `readLine` doesn't hang?

Comment: Is this your whole code or are there other uses of `scanner` before you get to the part that you showed us?

Comment: setText  is String and yes I used scanner object before to take input from user and when I used another scanner class object it runs fine. Thanks for that